# How to just re-install the kernel binary for Android-x86?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, android-x86

I can only build kernel with the following command in Android-x86 as described [here](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/customizekernel).

```
make kernel TARGET_PRODUCT=android_x86 TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG=android-x86_64_defconfig
```

But, I do not find how to just replace the kernel binary in currently installed Android-x86.
Could you provide any methods or pointers?